# Converting a unicode list into list of string in python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have this Unicode list

```
list = [u'Hello\n', u'23456\n', u'45678\n',u'85963\n'].
```

I want it to convert into the string list as below

```
list1 = ['Hello','23456','45678','85963']
```

With minimal code.

Comment: Don't use python keyword as variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str()` and `strip()` in a list comprehension :

```
>>> my_list = [u'Hello\n', u'23456\n', u'45678\n',u'85963\n']
>>> my_list = [str(i).strip() for i in my_list]
['Hello', '23456', '45678', '85963']
```

Note : dont use of python built-in functions as the variable names !

---

or you can use encode your unicodes to `ascii` by `encode('ascii','ignore')` :

```
>>> [i.encode('ascii','ignore').strip() for i in my_list]
['Hello', '23456', '45678', '85963']
```

Comment: I'll throw the map version of this into the mix as well. `map(lambda x: str(x).strip(), my_list)`

Comment: @limelights you could use it but it has less performance than list comprehension .

Comment: Of course, the creation of lambdas always takes time. :)

Comment: @limelights lambda in one reason even map has less performance than list comprehension !

Comment: it depends on what you use map for. In some cases map is faster.

Answer (score 0):

just convert all element of array in `string` using `str()` builtin
and then use `str.strip()` to remove spaces.

```
In [5]: list(str(i).strip() for i in _list)
Out[5]: ['Hello', '23456', '45678', '85963']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not use `list` as variable name. It is a reserved keyword in Python. 
Coming to your real problem, the best and most pythonic way to get what you want is:

```
xlist = [x.encode().rstrip('\n') for x in list]

print xlist
['Hello', '23456', '45678', '85963']
```

To know more, refer [str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) and [string.rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) methods.

Answer (score -1):

how about,

`for i in list:
    out.append(str(i)[0:-1])`